# How to separate similar tuples based on some similar attribute?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, tuples, scala-collections

I have a tuple list which looks like this:

```
val days= List(("Sunday", 1), ("Monday", 2), ("Tuesday", 1),
        ("Wednesday", 2), ("Thursday", 3), ("Friday", 2),
        ("Saturday", 3))
```

I want the final result to look like this:

```
"data": [
  [
    "Sunday, 1",
    "Tuesday, 1"
  ],
  [
    "Monday, 2",
    "Friday, 2"
    "Wednesday,2"
  ],
  [
    "Thursday, 3",
    "Saturday,3"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group and then map values:

```
days.groupBy(_._2)
    .mapValues(_.map { case (name, nr) => s"$name, $nr" } )
    .valuesIterator.toList
```

The result is:

```
 List(List(Monday, 2, Wednesday, 2, Friday, 2), List(Sunday, 1, Tuesday, 1), List(Thursday, 3, Saturday, 3))
```

P.S.: As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez suggests, using `groupMap` (from scala 2.13) can make this a bit more concise and readable:

```
days.groupMap(_._2) { case (name, nr) => s"$name, $nr" }
    .valuesIterator.toList
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I didn't play around 2.13 much, but I'll try to update, thank you

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm not sure I understand the second point, should I leave it without calling `toList`?

Comment: @Andronicus no no, together with the `toList`. So the point is simple, `values` returns a collection _(probably a list but who knows)_ with all values, then you convert that collection into a list, so instead of having an intermediate collection you can use `values Iterator` _(instead of `values`)_ to which you will immediately call `toList` which means there won't be an intermediate collection, just the final list.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ah, ok! How do you know there won't be any intermediate collection?

Comment: @Andronicus because an iterator is not a collection, is just a description of how to iterate all values. By being consumed directly with a `toList` you get a **List** without any intermediate step. However, I went looking to the sources _([`2.13`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L78), [`2.12`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.11/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L206))_ and it seems it was never an intermediate collection, the **Iterable** returned by `values` is actually an empty collection which forwards to the original map

Comment: In conclusion, use whatever you find better. I personally still prefer to use the iterator directly. Since technically speaking, `values` may change to return a List or a Vector or whatever, because the stdlib only promises to return an **Iterable**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've learned a lot by answering this simple question, thank you so much!